# Wcf from JQuery

Tags: jquery, wcf

I'm trying to invoke wcf service from Jquery Ajax. The service is usual Hello:

**Web Service**:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IHelloService
{
    [OperationContract]
   [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat =      WebMessageFormat.Json)]

    string GetMessage(string nome);

}

public class HelloService : IHelloService
{
    public string GetMessage(string nome)
    {
        return "Hello " + nome + "!";
    }
}
```

**Web Config**:

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>

        </behaviors>

        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
            multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
```

**Consumer**:

```
<script>
        $('#Button1').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:2021/HelloService.svc/GetMessage",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify($('#TextBox1').val()),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("ciao");
                    $('#Label1').html('Hello ' + data + '!');
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**Web.config Consumer**:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="EndpBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:2021/HelloService.svc" binding="webHttpBinding"
          contract="HelloServiceReference.IHelloService"
          behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior" />
   </client>

</system.serviceModel>
```

It give me error. The code inside "success" don't run.
I tryed with asp.net consumer and it go.

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.stringify({nome: $('#TextBox1').val() })`?

Comment: `It give me error` ... what error? Errors tell you what the problem is

Comment: Same error with JSON.stringify({nome: $('#TextBox1').val() }).

It say only "error"

Answer (score 0):

I found this tutorial

http://www.encodedna.com/wcf/tutorial/call-wcf-service-from-jquery-ajax-json-aspdotnet.htm

It goes only if consumer is inside the service project.

When i try to run web service the Visual Studio web client is empty.
It runs if I delete endpoint from web config, but then the consumer don't go The external consumer).

This the **web.config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Books" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior">

        <endpoint
            address=""
            binding="webHttpBinding"
            behaviorConfiguration="webEndPointBehavior"
            name="webEndPoint"
            contract="IBooks"/>

      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webEndPointBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
```